# I can't receive my message in my Android Device through google cloud messaging?

Tags: android, python, google-cloud-messaging

I am using python  as server app to send my message to GCM Server to receive  on registered android device. I am getting success from GCM server with message id.

On android mobile I am receiving data in `arg1` in `onMessage()` function but with just two keys in `arg1`, `from` & `collapse_key`.

In below Java Code, `from` key contains a `LongInt` value & `message` is `null`.

Can anybody tell me what thing i am missing in Java Code or in Python Code.?

**Here is my JavaCode:**

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String keys="";
    for (String key : arg1.getExtras().keySet())
        keys+=key+"||";
    String mess = arg1.getExtras().getString("from");
    String mess1 = arg1.getExtras().getString("message");
}
```

**Python Code:**

```
def SelectAction(request,client_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':

        message = request.GET.get('message','')
        if not message:
            return Error(message = "Argument Missing.")
        registration=  Registration.objects.get(registeredUser = user)
        values = {}
        values['registration_id'] = registration.appId
        values['data.message'] = message
        param = urllib.urlencode(values)
        req = urllib2.Request("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send", param)
        req.add_header( 'Content-Type' , 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' )
        req.add_header( 'Authorization' , 'key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        reply = {}
        if response.read().split('=')[0] == 'id':
            reply['error'] = '0'
        else:
            reply['error'] = '1'

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(reply), mimetype="application/javascript")
    else:
        return Error()
```

Comment: What http response do you get when sending messages?

Comment: I get 200 OK with plain text response  containing id . e.g. "id=0:1345461917515289%ebf0d4f3f9fd7ecd"

Comment: Okay, that means that the message has been sent correctly. Do you ever get into onMessage Method? :) 
Can we see whole receiver class and android manifest xml pls

Comment: Are you sure that line 'param = urllib.urlencode(values)' works well?

Comment: @IgorKhomenko yes it works perfectly that's why i am getting 200 response from google server with message id in call response.

Comment: @AndersMetnik yes my onMessage get called with always response with just two keys in arg1, from & collapse_key but no message key :(

Comment: Btw. writing arg0 and arg1 is bad variable naming: call it ctx/context and intent or something like that so people reading your code easily know what you refer too.

Answer (score 0):

Try extract the data before you do something else:

```
Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
        if (data != null) {
            data.isEmpty(); toString();
        }
```

Now you can use toString(); and see what the data contains:

```
Log.i("C2DM", data.toString());
```

check the log for C2DM and paste what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be set up correctly. It seems to me like that the message is never sent in the first place to your server. Since you can retrieve the from but not message, this is probably correct.

In the server, can you change the following line;

```
values['data.message'] = message
```

to this;

```
values['data.message'] = "testMessage"
```

I think this will most likely lead to you getting the message in android.. Just temporarily change the message to see if the push is working to begin with..